# how to write this clojure.java.jdbc select where clause

Tags: mysql, clojure

How can I implement **select * from fruit where cost > 22 and cost < 44** w/ DSL way, by example below from [clojure/java.jdbc demo](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc):

```
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as j]
     '[clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as s])

(def mysql-db {:subprotocol "mysql"
               :subname "//127.0.0.1:3306/clojure_test"
               :user "clojure_test"
               :password "clojure_test"})

(j/insert! mysql-db :fruit
  {:name "Apple" :appearance "rosy" :cost 24}
  {:name "Orange" :appearance "round" :cost 49})
;; ({:generated_key 1} {:generated_key 2})

(j/query mysql-db
  (s/select * :fruit (s/where {:appearance "rosy"}))
  :row-fn :cost)
;; (24)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` function only supports `=` comparison. What you can do is instead of `(s/where {..})` you can put a vector which represent the query part: `["cost > ? AND cost < ?" 22 44]`

Comment: I think you mean: instead of `(s/where)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the SQL DSL has been removed from `clojure.java.jdbc`, the recommended approach is to use [HoneySQL](https://github.com/jkk/honeysql) for the DSL (as explained in the README for `clojure.java.jdbc`).